# How to use Reporting Snapshots and get the output report link?

Tags: reporting, custom-object, standard-objects, analytic-snapshots

Created snapshot for the opportunity and done field mapping and scheduled the time also.

While getting automatic mail from salesforce regarding record inserted, "how can i provide a link to the actual snapshot, meaning the Opportunity report generated as of that date".

Can i do some changes in that mail format which is automatically generated by SF or any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to refer to the standard feature called Reporting Snapshot (aka Analytic Snapshot).

Therefore you should work through the manual here

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_about_analytic_snap.htm&language=en_US

You basically setup a Custom Object as a container for snapshot data on an other tabular or matrix report.

> Authorized users can save tabular or summary report results to fields
>   on a custom object, then map those fields to corresponding fields on a
>   target object.

One record of the target Custom Object corresponds to a snapshot or one point in time. Each field of the custom object maps to an (usually aggregated) result from the source report.

The target report can be setup to run in regular intervals. This doesn't mean a new report is generated every time.

So after you have setup everything an run it the first time, just open the output report and grab it's url from the browser. This is your report link.

I don't think you can customize the automatic email from salesforce.

Comment: How should i able to access (in Salesforce) the historical data as of the date it was captured